# Inserting JSON in to PostgreSQL, how to avoid unescaped characters

Tags: java, json, postgresql

I am filling a database in PostgreSQL with JSON objects from a Java based application, and I have had many cases where the program would throw an exception like 
ERROR: invalid input syntax for type json
  Detail: Character with value 0x0a must be escaped.
Now i know I can easily use replace all to deal with the escaped characters.
But my question is if I could somehow skip those invalid statements or if there is a way to deal with all the characters that should be escaped at once so I don't need to write replaceAll code for every case.