# pg nodejs package results in 'invalid input syntax for type json'

Tags: json, node.js, postgresql, syntax-error, pg

I have following setup for my project, using the [pg](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pg) node-postgres package:

[image]

The simple table 'tmp' looks like this:

[image]

According to [jsonORG](http://json.org/) and the [postgres docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/datatype-json.html) the object:

```
{"foo" : true}
```

is syntactically valid JSON, and when using the pgAdmin Query-tool with:

```
UPDATE tmp SET data = '{"foo": false}' WHERE id = '1'
```

works fine, but when i try updating my table through my express route using pg:

```
router.put('/updateTMP', (req, res) => {
    // I use dummies in this case instead of req.body.someKey for testing purposes
    let dummyJSON = {"foo":true};
    let dummyID = 1;
    pg.query(`UPDATE tmp SET data = '${dummyJSON}' WHERE id = '${dummyID}'`, (errUpdate, responseUpdate) => {
        if (!errUpdate) { // NO ERROR
            res.json({success: true, message: responseUpdate});
        }
        else { // ERROR
            console.log(dummyJSON);
            console.log(errUpdate);
            res.json({success: false, message: errUpdate}); 
        }
    })
})
```

I get the following error from the database:

```
error: invalid input syntax for type json
```

I've tried the [to_json](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-json.html) function from postgresql and the [to-json package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/to-json) from npm in the express route - all with the same negative result.

Am i missing some fundamental understanding or is it some formating/quoting-issue?

Thanks in advance for your ideas! ;)

ps: And yes - I've read through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31873723/inserting-json-in-to-postgresql-how-to-avoid-unescaped-characters), and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45971754/preventing-invalid-input-syntax-for-type-json-in-postgres) article..

Comment: even when i try to pass {"":""} to postgresql's to_json() function, I get following error: 'could not determine polymorphic type because input has type "unknown"'..

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I had the same problem. Try converting your JS object to string using `JSON.stringify()` before passing it into the query as pg won't always do that for you automatically.

See this [**issue**](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/issues/442) on GitHub for more info.

Comment: very accurate answer bro thanks!