# How to update postgres jsonb with dynamic variables in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, json, postgresql, jsonb

I'm trying to understand what I'm doing wrong. I keep getting a json syntax error when trying to run this query to update my table. This is the error I see in the console

> error: invalid input syntax for type json

What would be the right syntax for this update query?

```
var acc_status = 'active';
var token = '9n98jpmimuj94t24t';

pool.query("UPDATE users SET info = JSONB_SET(info, '{auth,acc_status}', '"+acc_status+"') WHERE info -> 'auth' -> 'validation' ->> 'token' = '"+token+"' RETURNING *", (err, res) => {
if (err) {

//log errors
console.log(err.stack);

//return error to client

} else {

//success
console.log(res.rows);

//broadcast
io.emit('activateAccount',res.rows);

}
});
```

If I run this in PgAdmin Query tool it works

```
UPDATE users SET info = JSONB_SET(info, '{auth,acc_status}', '"active"') 
WHERE info -> 'auth' -> 'validation' ->> 'token' = '9n98jpmimuj94t24t';
```

Comment: What syntax error?

Comment: You're adding double quotes around your `token` that don't exist in the pgadmin query. But that shouldn't cause a syntax error, just not match any row. But this is a bad idea anyway, use a [parameterised query](https://node-postgres.com/features/queries#parameterized-query)!

Comment: @Bergi : found the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51079864/pg-nodejs-package-results-in-invalid-input-syntax-for-type-json#51756759